# Horizontal tree view without expand collapse in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to implement a horizontal tree view without expand/collapse feature in plain HTML. But i couldn't find any. Help me.

**Example:**

[image]

If there is any library, please let me know.

Comment: You might want to check out [this library](https://www.jstree.com/). What have you tried searching for so far (or what results did you get closest to)? You could also try to develop your own tree if it'll become too specific (not allowing for expand/collapse). This is what I did for my current project.

Comment: @Barrosy, I saw that library but I don't want expand/collapse functionality. Just a tree view with circles at the end.

Comment: Have you tried developing something on your own? Is there any problem you are having with any of your own written code?

Comment: Yeah I tried this - https://jsfiddle.net/Lk83qvpn/

Comment: Let me first help you out with one thing: You are making use of a selector multiple times within your CSS. Please take a look at your code and check the errors within the Fiddle. (if you do not understand any of the errors, please check Stackoverflow for more information and if you really cannot find anything, you could comment here "as last resort".) I will try if I can fiddle an example for you.

Comment: To get you to a certain direction: You could do something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/fmqeypj7/1/), create your own custom HTML, CSS and JavaScript to create a tree (quite a simple example, I am aware).

Answer (score 1):

Please Checkout this , This is what you require..
here is the codepen demo https://codepen.io/Vikaspatel/pen/Ybwqew

```css
ul{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
}
.wrapper {
 max-width: 800px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 600px;
 background-color: #eeeeee;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 10px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}
.wrapper li {
 width: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
}
.wrapper li::before {
 position: absolute;
 content: "";
 width: 100px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: #333333;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
 top: 15px;
}
.circle {
 height: 30px;
 width: 30px;
 display: block;
 background-color: #8cef46;
 border-radius: 50%;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 30px;
}
.children {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 left: 100%;
 height: 300px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
.children.first-child.top-child {
 height: 150px;
}
.children.first-child.bottom-child {
 height: 230px;
}
.children.second-child.bottom-child {
 height: 126px;
}
.children.second-child.top-child {
 height: 30px;
}
.children.third-child.top-child {
 height: 80px;
}
.children.first-child.bottom-child .children.second-child.top-child,
.children.first-child.bottom-child .children.second-child.middle-child {
 height: 30px;
}
.children.first-child.bottom-child .children.second-child.bottom-child{
 height:120px;
}
.children::before {
 position: absolute;
 content: "";
 left: 0;
 width: 2px;
 background-color: #333333;
 top: 15px;
 bottom: 15px;
}
.wrapper .last-child li::before {
 width: 50px;
 left: 0;
 transform: translateX(0);
}
.red{
 background-color: #D8A7C8;
}
.green{
 background-color: #B0EE91;
}
.purple{
 background-color: #8D9BF4;
}
.yellow{
 background-color: #F8E2A9;
}
.brown{
 background-color:#8D869A;
}
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="parent">
   <li>
    <span class="circle green">12</span>
    <ul class="children first-child">
     <li>
      <span class="circle red">3</span>
      <ul class="children first-child top-child">
       <li>
        <span class="circle brown">6</span>
        <ul class="children second-child top-child">
         <li>
          <span class="circle">14</span>
          <ul class="children third-child top-child last-child">
           <li>
            <span class="circle red">11</span>
           </li>
           <li>
            <span class="circle yellow">1</span>
           </li>
          </ul>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li>
        <span class="circle purple">13</span>
        <ul class="children second-child bottom-child last-child">
         <li>
          <span class="circle red">2</span>
         </li>
         <li>
          <span class="circle green">5</span>
         </li>
         <li>
          <span class="circle purple">19</span>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li>
      <span class="circle yellow">0</span>
      <ul class="children first-child bottom-child">
       <li>
        <span class="circle red">9</span>
        <ul class="children second-child top-child last-child">
         <li>
          <span class="circle">15</span>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li>
        <span class="circle">16</span>
        <ul class="children second-child middle-child last-child">
         <li>
          <span class="circle purple">7</span>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li>
        <span class="circle purple">4</span>
        <ul class="children second-child bottom-child last-child">
         <li>
          <span class="circle red">8</span>
         </li>
         <li>
          <span class="circle green">17</span>
         </li>
         <li>
          <span class="circle brown">20</span>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```